# Is there any code sample that integrates Laravel with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, postcss

I am trying to add Tailwind CSS to my freshly created Laravel project, I went to [Tailwind CSS documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel)

What I have added in my **webapack.mix.js** is the line `.sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")` and `require("tailwind")`.

I have also added:

```
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
```

to my dependencies to my **package.json**, ran `npm install` and when I run `npm run dev` it throws me the error like this

```
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
    at Processor.normalize (D:\blog\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:61:15)
    at new Processor (D:\blog\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:10:25)
    at postcss (D:\blog\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:26:10)
    at Object.loader (D:\blog\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:87:20)
    at processResult (D:\blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:703:19)
    at D:\blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:809:5
    at D:\blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at D:\blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (D:\blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (D:\blog\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:96:7)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rafay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-28T19_41_44_049Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rafay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-28T19_41_44_083Z-debug.log
```

This is my folder structure of my project [image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the following is all in the [`TailwindCSS` docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel) and you've followed them, but just for conciseness lets start at the beginning.

You don't need to use `sass` processors with `TailwindCSS`, you can customise `TailwindCSS` through the `tailwind.config.js` file.

Add `tailwindcss` to your `package.json` `devDependencies`. You might also want to include the optional `forms` and `typography` packages.

```json
"@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
"@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
"autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
"postcss": "^8.1.14",
"postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
"tailwindcss": "^2.0.1"
```

Update your `webpack.mix.js` file to `require` `tailwindcss` etc.

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]);
```

Initialise your `tailwind.config.js`.

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

Add the base styles to your `app.css` file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

In order to keep your CSS filesize small, tell Tailwind to purge any CSS styles that are not found in files specified in the `purge` array of your `tailwind.config.js` file. You can add/remove as you see fit.

```
purge: [
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.js',
    './resources/views/**/*.vue',
],
```

If you have installed and configured it correctly, you should be able to run `npm run dev` successfully.

You can find an example repo with a fresh install of [Laravel and TailwindCSS here](https://github.com/peppermintology/laravel-tailwindcss) if that helps.

Comment: I will try this and let you know in a few minutes.

Comment: @AbdulRafay I have added an example repo for you to clone if that helps.

Comment: this actually worked, thank you so very much